# How to get value from input thymleaf and post to controller with th href spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have problem with thymleaf spring boot, my input is like this

```
<input class="-Text" type="text" style="border:none" placeholder="1234567890xx" th:value="${sn}" name="sn"/>
```

I want to get parse the value from input to my th href thymleaf code like this

```
<a id="btnx" th:href="@{/pages/input-order-manual/finish-confirm/?sn=__${sn}__}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Confirm</a>
```

But when I try to run, this value always return **null** for my sn variable, what must I do, to make this code run?

For any help, 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Insert full code. Run code in debug, add break point before return template and make sure you have sn variable in model. Also you can concat th:href (th:href="@{/pages/input-order-manual/finish-confirm/?} + ${sn}")